# Responsive design with scrolling text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm usually pretty good with getting things responsive but the scrolling text I am using is making it too complicated for me to work out!

I've got some fixed text, then the scrolling text with CSS animation, then another line of fixed text below.
I can align them easily in the right place using absolute positioning, but I can't get it to behave responsively and it keeps throwing it out when I resize the screen. Tried adding a text wrapper to all the text to align that but it's not working.

I've had quite a play about with the code but hoping someone can help me :)

Any help really appreciated!

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* position: fixed; */
}

.header-wrapper {
  background: rgb(251, 186, 10);
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, rgba(251, 186, 10, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 212, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 237, 60, 1) 100%);
  width: 1440px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  /* position: relative; */
}

.all-text-wrap {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 1440px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* margin: auto; */
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  width: 800px;
}

.content__container {
  font-weight: 900;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 55px;
  /* padding: 0 40px; */
}

.content__container__list {
  margin-top: 0;
  /* padding-left: 110px; */
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-animation-name: change;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: change;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  padding: 0;
}

.content__container__list__item {
  line-height: 55px;
  margin: 0;
}

.intro-headline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21%;
  left: 35%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  width: 800px;
}

.intro-subline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  width: 800px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes change {
  0%,
  7.11%,
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  11.11%,
  18.22% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -11.11%, 0);
  }
  22.22%,
  29.33% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -22.22%, 0);
  }
  33.33%,
  40.44% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -33.33%, 0);
  }
  44.44%,
  51.55% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -44.44%, 0);
  }
  55.55%,
  62.66% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -55.55%, 0);
  }
  66.66%,
  73.77% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -66.66%, 0);
  }
  77.77%,
  84.88% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -77.77%, 0);
  }
  88.88%,
  95.99% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -88.88%, 0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes opacity {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes change {
  0%,
  7.11%,
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  11.11%,
  18.22% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -11.11%, 0);
  }
  22.22%,
  29.33% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -22.22%, 0);
  }
  33.33%,
  40.44% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -33.33%, 0);
  }
  44.44%,
  51.55% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -44.44%, 0);
  }
  55.55%,
  62.66% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -55.55%, 0);
  }
  66.66%,
  73.77% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -66.66%, 0);
  }
  77.77%,
  84.88% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -77.77%, 0);
  }
  88.88%,
  95.99% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -88.88%, 0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes opacity {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes change {
  0%,
  7.11%,
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  11.11%,
  18.22% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -11.11%, 0);
  }
  22.22%,
  29.33% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -22.22%, 0);
  }
  33.33%,
  40.44% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -33.33%, 0);
  }
  44.44%,
  51.55% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -44.44%, 0);
  }
  55.55%,
  62.66% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -55.55%, 0);
  }
  66.66%,
  73.77% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -66.66%, 0);
  }
  77.77%,
  84.88% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -77.77%, 0);
  }
  88.88%,
  95.99% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -88.88%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes opacity {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes change {
  0%,
  7.11%,
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  11.11%,
  18.22% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -11.11%, 0);
  }
  22.22%,
  29.33% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -22.22%, 0);
  }
  33.33%,
  40.44% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -33.33%, 0);
  }
  44.44%,
  51.55% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -44.44%, 0);
  }
  55.55%,
  62.66% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -55.55%, 0);
  }
  66.66%,
  73.77% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -66.66%, 0);
  }
  77.77%,
  84.88% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -77.77%, 0);
  }
  88.88%,
  95.99% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -88.88%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Scrolling Text</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="all-text-wrap">
      <div class="intro-headline">DO SUMMER</div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content__container">
          <ul class="content__container__list">
            <li class="content__container__list__item">SUNRISE RUNS</li>
            <li class="content__container__list__item">MORNING COFFEES</li>
            <li class="content__container__list__item">PARK PICNICS</li>
            <li class="content__container__list__item">CITY STROLLS</li>
            <li class="content__container__list__item">STREET MARKETS</li>
            <li class="content__container__list__item">ARTS FAIRS</li>
            <li class="content__container__list__item">MUSIC FESTIVALS</li>
            <li class="content__container__list__item">ALFRESCO EVENINGS</li>
            <li class="content__container__list__item">URBAN SUNSETS</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="intro-subline">WITH US</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you're looking for, here's a solution.

No absolute positioning, just match your line height with your scrolling text box's element height, and let the text rows flow. Use `flex` to position the whole thing horizontally (center).

Also don't force the width of the wrapper (`.all-text-wrap`), as the value you had (800px) leaded to some scrolling lines being wrapped. Let it grow as required by setting it as an inline-block with max-width 100%;

On small screens though, it won't look good, as scrolling lines will either overflow or have to wrap. I used media queries to change the value of variable `--font-size` to fix it (no wrapping required anymore). *I could also have adjusted `--line-height`.*

```css
:root {
  --font-size: 70px;
  --line-height: calc(var(--font-size) + 0px); /*adjust line spacing */
}

html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

.header-wrapper {
  width: 1440px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgb(251, 186, 10);
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, rgba(251, 186, 10, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 212, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 237, 60, 1) 100%);
}

.all-text-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  line-height: var(--line-height);
  color: #2f2f2f;
}

.content {
  height: var(--line-height);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.content__container__list {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  animation: change 10s infinite;
}

.content__container__list__item {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@keyframes change {
  0%,
  7.11%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  11.11%,
  18.22% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-1 * var(--line-height)));
  }
  22.22%,
  29.33% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-2 * var(--line-height)));
  }
  33.33%,
  40.44% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-3 * var(--line-height)));
  }
  44.44%,
  51.55% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-4 * var(--line-height)));
  }
  55.55%,
  62.66% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-5 * var(--line-height)));
  }
  66.66%,
  73.77% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-6 * var(--line-height)));
  }
  77.77%,
  84.88% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-7 * var(--line-height)));
  }
  88.88%,
  95.99% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-8 * var(--line-height)));
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  :root {
    --font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  :root {
    --font-size: 40px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  :root {
    --font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Scrolling Text</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="all-text-wrap">
      <div class="intro-headline">DO SUMMER</div>
      <div class="content">
        <ul class="content__container__list">
          <li class="content__container__list__item">SUNRISE RUNS</li>
          <li class="content__container__list__item">MORNING COFFEES</li>
          <li class="content__container__list__item">PARK PICNICS</li>
          <li class="content__container__list__item">CITY STROLLS</li>
          <li class="content__container__list__item">STREET MARKETS</li>
          <li class="content__container__list__item">ARTS FAIRS</li>
          <li class="content__container__list__item">MUSIC FESTIVALS</li>
          <li class="content__container__list__item">ALFRESCO EVENINGS</li>
          <li class="content__container__list__item">URBAN SUNSETS</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="intro-subline">WITH US</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed - thank you so much!